# Having trouble with resizing/viewports

Tags: html, css, viewport

I can't get it right so that the content within my `<body>` stays at the middle (`margin-left / margin-right`) distances the entire time, even when they are extended. Currently, I have the header (navbar) and storyboard working, although the body does not seem to situate itself properly because I am not sure how to code this.

When I coded it, I used margin distances and widths to satisfy a screen resolution in full screen of `1280x720`, where it was centered, but when I open the website on a `1920x1080`, the body is situated more to the left due to this.

On a 1080p resolution:

[image: 1080p 100% view]

[image: pic]

[image: lol]

As you can see above, when really extended the content is still situated to the left. It can't be margins because I did not use any in my CSS, it is embedded within .container which has no CSS, so how could I center all of this?

The CSS for this is:

[image: css]

These 2 divs/sections are embedded within the main div container, which is the entire body. The row is the three pictures you see, and the .info is the following information underneath. Maybe positioning this central will transfer all the other content within it to be central as well? I currently have no code for the .container either, so I'm not sure what I would do.

Comment: use max-with above two class

Comment: I have answered similar question in this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814878/css3-flexbox-spacing-between-items/30816104#30816104](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814878/css3-flexbox-spacing-between-items/30816104#30816104)....................... also you can use ................................ @media screen and (min-width: 1920px){ ... your style code......}

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto;` is a great option for horizontal alignment.

See http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Sean

Comment: I am using that within my .container, however it does not change where it is situated.. it's like it is locked to that position?